# parse custom algebraic datatype from json

Tags: json, haskell

For instance i have such json file with some entities(modules):

```
{ 
    "name"  : "module1",
    "type"   : "Type1"
},

{
    "name"  : "module2",
    "type"   : "Type2"
}
```

And i want to construct my datatype Module from this json

```
data Module = Module {name::String, type :: ModuleType}

data ModuleType = Type1 | Type2
```

What is the most convenient way of building such kind of datatype from json? How can i parse my custom types Type1 and Type2, transform and validate them? Any help will be appreciated =)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use the amazing [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson/0.6.1.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson.html) module. It's very fast, very easy to understand and you can quickly develop the parsing logic. It even has some examples at the beginning of the page and you can use that example 99% in your code.

```
instance FromJSON Module where
    parseJSON (Object v) = build <$>
                           v .: "name" <*>
                           v .: "type"
    -- A non-Object value is of the wrong type, so fail.
    parseJSON _          = mzero

build :: String -> String -> Module
build name "Type1" = Module name Type1
build name "Type2" = Module name Type2
```

Comment: Thanks, i've already looked at it. And it's first example shows how to parse Person datatype that has Int and Text properties, can you point how to implement parsing my custom datatype in this way, in my case ModuleType?

Comment: You can use that example, no changes needed beside switching on the value of `type` to select the proper constructor.

Comment: sorry but can't deal how to write instance FromJSON for my ModuleType, can you provide some code snippet?

Comment: Added. Untested since I'm not at a computer with Haskell installed. But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to write your own `FromJSON` instance for the `ModuleType` datatype:

```
instance FromJSON Module where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Module <$>
                           v .: "name" <*>
                           v .: "type"
    parseJSON _          = mzero

instance FromJSON ModuleType where
    parseJSON (String t) = case t of
                               "Type1" -> return Type1
                               "Type2" -> return Type2
                               _       -> mzero
    parseJSON _          = mzero
```

This way you don't run into `non-exhaustive pattern` errors (as might happen with Mihai's solution) when somebody gives you a string like

```
{ "name": "module1", "type": "unconventional-type" }
```

to decode.